# Last Page show above google maps plugin on framework 7 phonegap

Tags: android, phonegap-plugins, google-maps-android-api-2, phonegap, html-framework-7

I'm new on phonegap and i want to use google maps plugin for phonegap. But when i use framework 7, the app load the map without problem but then it appear part of the last screen.

For Example:

When I open the app i'm in index.html, then when i click on map button of menu for 1 second i got the map without problem, but then part of the index.html shows with transparency above my map

map.html

```
<!-- We don't need a full layout in this file because this page will be parsed with Ajax. -->

<!-- Top Navbar-->
<div class="navbar ">
<div class="navbar-inner">
    <div class="left">

    </div>
    <div class="center sliding">

    </div>
    <div class="right">

    </div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="pages">
 <div data-page="mapa" class="page hidden-navbar no-navbar no-toolbar">
     <div class="page-content">
         <div style="background-color: white">
             <div style="width:100%;height:300px" id="map_canvas"></div>
             <br><br><br><br><br><br>
            <p class="button" id="boton_mapa"><a href="#">Cuadrar</a></p>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

javascript:

```
var myApp = new Framework7({
swipePanel: 'left',
});

var $$ = Dom7;


var mainView = myApp.addView('.view-main', {
// Because we want to use dynamic navbar, we need to enable it for this view:
dynamicNavbar: true
});

// Handle Cordova Device Ready Event
$$(document).on('deviceready', function() {
    console.log("Device is ready!");
});

document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

var map;

myApp.onPageInit('mapa', function (page) {

  myApp.closePanel();

})

myApp.onPageAfterAnimation('mapa', function (page) {

var div = document.getElementById("map_canvas");

map = plugin.google.maps.Map.getMap(div);


map.addEventListener(plugin.google.maps.event.MAP_READY, onMapReady);

})




function onMapReady() {
var button = document.getElementById("boton_mapa");

map.animateCamera({
target: {lat: -12.196486, lng: -77.002614},
zoom: 17,
tilt: 60,
bearing: 140,
});

  button.addEventListener("click", onButtonClick);
}

function onButtonClick() {

// Move to the position with animation
map.animateCamera({
target: {lat: -12.196486, lng: -77.002614},
zoom: 17,
tilt: 60,
bearing: 140,
}, function() {

// Add a maker
map.addMarker({
  position: {lat: -12.196486, lng: -77.002614},
  title: "YY",
  snippet: "Decripción Corta 1"
}, function(marker) {

  // Show the info window
  marker.showInfoWindow();

  // Catch the click event
  marker.on(plugin.google.maps.event.INFO_CLICK, function() {

    // To do something...
    alert("Hello world!");

  });
  });

  map.addMarker({
  position: {lat: -12.197486, lng: -77.003614},
  title: "XX",
  snippet: "Decripción Corta 2"
  });





 });
 }
```

I'm using this documentation at most of code of the official site https://github.com/mapsplugin/cordova-plugin-googlemaps

[image: From index.html]
[image: From mapa.html]

index.html
mapa.html in that order ( sorry for big pictures )
Any idea would be great! thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I personally gave the last pages some HTML IDs to hide them onMapReady and show them on page:beforeout